# Adding Schema Name to SQL Table Names in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am porting my SQL Server database to Azure SQL. The database has been replicated correctly and is now accessible from my existing web application.

However, the first time it was executed with the Azure SQL connection string, it showed "Invalid Object" for a table name used on the log in page.

I was able to correct it by adding the schema name `[dbusername].[tablename]` in place of `[tablename]` in the code.

Now since it is an extensive application, with over 300 ASPX pages and 30 tables, I'm wondering do I have to use the Find-Replace tool in Visual Studio or am I missing a setting that can help me to assign the default schema name while executing all queries ?

Comment: Do you have a *DataAccess layer* that references the tables. or are you using inline SQL in the pages' code behind?

Comment: @christiandev - inline SQL is used, hence the amount of pages to be checked and replaced is huge.

Comment: This highlights the issues when using **inline sql** in code-behind, but you are where you are as they say.  I guess a careful find and replace is the quick and dirty solution, but I would consider at least placing these queries in a data-access layer (making sure you address any potential sql injection attacks along the way)

Comment: @christiandev - a totally valid point. it's a 4 year old project, and hence these naive mechanisms used by the previous developers. i guess the careful find-replace is the only way out here.

Comment: 4 years isn't so long ago, I would certainly look at investing some time into moving the queries into a separate library, it probably wouldn't even take too long.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default schema for your user.

```
USE MyDataBase;
GO
ALTER USER MyUser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=MySchema;
GO
```

Comment: I tried that. The following error pops up - _"Cannot alter the user 'bhradmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."_

Comment: Using an admin user to connect to the database is a *bad* idea. Create a different user *non-admin* user, specific to your web application and assign the default schema.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this article will help you.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/26/sql-server-fix-error-msg-15151-level-16-state-1-line-2-cannot-alter-the-login-sa-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permission/